# encode string from json utf-8

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a JSON file `{"data":[{"clientName":"Is Такой текст"}]}` that is UTF-8 encoded, and I am trying to see the text in the tag `clientName` using the `ShowMessage()` function.

Instead of normal text, I get "Is strangeText". I understand that the problem is in the encoding, but I don't understand how to fix it.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.jsonTest;
var
  JSONData, JSON: TJSONObject;
  jArr: TJSONArray;
  s: TStringList;
  i, j: Integer;
  jValue: TJSonValue;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  jPair: TJSONPair;
begin
  json := TJSONObject.Create;
  s := TStringList.Create;
  try
    S.LoadFromFile('clientOrders.json');
    text := S.Text;
    JSON := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(BytesOf(text),0) as TJSONObject;
    if JSON <> nil then
    begin
      jPair := JSON.Get(0);
      jArr := jPair.JsonValue as TJSONArray;

      for I := 0 to jArr.Size-1 do
      begin
        JSONData := jArr.Get(I) as TJSONObject;

        for j := 0 to JSONData.Size - 1 do
        begin
          ShowMessage(JSONData.Get(j).JsonValue.ToString);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
      raise Exception.Create('This is not a JSON');
  finally
    json.Free;
    s.Free;
    jValue.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Because of the policy of this site I've deleted some code. It is said that I must write more text, but don't know what to write. 
Exactly some code looks like - 
JSON:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(BytesOf(StripNonJson(text)),0) as TJSONObject;

and function
function TForm1.StripNonJson(s: string): string;
var
  ch: char;
  inString: boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  inString := false;
  for ch in s do
  begin
    if ch = '"' then
      inString := not inString;
    if TCharacter.IsWhiteSpace(ch) and not inString then
      continue;
    Result := Result + ch;
  end;
end;

Comment: Not sure why you're using BytesOf. You can parse text this way: `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(text)`

Comment: Because of 
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(177): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'ParseJSONValue' that can be called with these arguments
I cant even use JSONData.Get('someName') as shown in some examples.

Comment: @DaveNottage, have a look at the Delphi version in tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running this code on Windows, then the problem is two-fold:

- you are not telling `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` what the encoding of the file is. So, unless the file begins with a UTF-8 BOM (which is unlikely with a JSON file), it will be decoded as ANSI, not as UTF-8, thus corrupting any NON-ASCII characters.
- you are converting the decoded text back into bytes without specifying an encoding. The overload of `ParseJSONValue()` you are using expects UTF-8 encoded bytes, but `BytesOf()` will encode to ANSI, not to UTF-8, thus corrupting non-ASCII characters even futher.

That is why you are getting garbage text from the JSON.

There are other problems with your code, too. Namely, a memory leak and a double-free, due to you mismanaging the initlal `TJSONObject`.

Try this instead.

```
procedure TForm1.jsonTest;
var
  JSONData, JSON: TJSONObject;
  jArr: TJSONArray;
  s: TStringList;
  i, j: Integer;
  jValue: TJSonValue;
  data: string;
begin
  s := TStringList.Create;
  try
    s.LoadFromFile('clientOrders.json', TEncoding.UTF8);
    data := s.Text;
  finally
    s.Free;
  end;
  { Alternatively:
  data := IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText('clientOrders.json', TEncoding.UTF8);
  }
  jValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 0);
  if jValue = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('This is not a JSON');
  try
    JSON := jValue as TJSONObject;
    jArr := JSON.Get(0).JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    for I := 0 to jArr.Size-1 do
    begin
      JSONData := jArr.Get(I) as TJSONObject;
       for j := 0 to JSONData.Size - 1 do
       begin
         ShowMessage(JSONData.Get(j).JsonValue.ToString);
       end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    jValue.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, don't decode the file bytes into a `string` just to convert them back into bytes, just load them as-is into `ParseJSONValue()`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.jsonTest;
var
  ...
  jValue: TJSonValue;
  data: TBytesStream;
begin
  data := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    data.LoadFromFile('clientOrders.json');
    jValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(data.Bytes, 0);
    ...
  finally
    data.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.jsonTest;
var
  ...
  jValue: TJSonValue;
  data: TBytes;
begin
  data := IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllBytes('clientOrders.json');
  jValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(data, 0);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank You very much. But without 
`function TForm1.StripNonJson(s: string): string;
var
  ch: char;
  inString: boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  inString := false;
  for ch in s do
  begin
    if ch = '"' then
      inString := not inString;
    if TCharacter.IsWhiteSpace(ch) and not inString then
      continue;
    Result := Result + ch;
  end;
end;`  I always get This is not a JSON. With this function I get the same result with strange text.

Comment: That function does not change the JSON you have shown, as there is no *unquoted* whitespace in it. But, if the presence/lack of such function causes `ParseJSONValue()` to produce different results, there must be something wrong with your JSON to begin with, as you should NOT have to strip off ANY characters at all (which, BTW, your function doesn't take *escaped* quote characters into account). The JSON you have shown is perfectly valid as-is, and `ParseJSONValue()` should handle it just fine. Which implies the JSON you have shown is not the real JSON you are actually working with.

Comment: I' m not alone with json identification problem. I've found "stripnonJson' function here. There is even link to embarcadero with the same function - https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40882
https://gist.github.com/fabriciocolombo/4236ce010787d86b5c65
I think this is unlucky version of DBXJSON. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know why the original DBXJSON code needed `StripNonJson()` (which, as I mentioned earlier, is incomplete), that must have been a workaround for a bug in the old parser. Modern Delphi's `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` does not require any stripping.

Comment: With function below I've totally solved the problem.

function TForm1.UnicodeToJSON(source: string): string;
var
 ch: char;
 code: smallint;
 i: integer;
begin
 result := '';
 for i := 1 to length(source) do
 begin
  ch := source[i];
  code := ord(ch);
  if code > 127 then
   result := result + '\u' + IntToHex(code, 4)
  else
   result := result + source[i];
 end;
end;